# Problema con update a base de datos SQLite desde Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Buenas. Tengo un problema para actualizar datos en una base de datos SQLITE. Pongo el código necesario:

Variables:

```
public static final String TABLE_INVENTARIO_NAME = "inventario";
public static final String INV_NOMBRE="inv_nombre";
public static final String INV_TIPO="inv_tipo";
public static final String INV_NUMERO="inv_numero";
public static final String INV_IMAGEN="inv_imagen";
```

Creación de la base de datos:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INVENTARIO_NAME + " ("
                +"ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
                +INV_NUMERO + "INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +INV_TIPO + "INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +INV_NOMBRE + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
                +INV_IMAGEN + "INTEGER NOT NULL)");
```

Creación de un registro inicial:

```
ContentValues registroInventario = new ContentValues();
registroInventario.put("ID",1);
registroInventario.put(AccesoDB.INV_NOMBRE,inv1_nombre);
registroInventario.put(AccesoDB.INV_TIPO,inv1_tipo);
registroInventario.put(AccesoDB.INV_NUMERO,inv1_numero);
registroInventario.put(AccesoDB.INV_IMAGEN,inv1_imagen);
bd.insert(AccesoDB.TABLE_INVENTARIO_NAME,null,registroInventario);
```

Y el método para actualizar:

```
private void actualizarInventario(Context context,String valorNombre, int valorImagen, int valorTipo, int valorNumero, int id){
    acceso = new AccesoDB(context);
    bd = acceso.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put(AccesoDB.INV_NOMBRE,valorNombre);
    valores.put(AccesoDB.INV_TIPO,valorTipo);
    valores.put(AccesoDB.INV_NUMERO,valorNumero);
    valores.put(AccesoDB.INV_IMAGEN,valorImagen);
    int up=bd.update(AccesoDB.TABLE_INVENTARIO_NAME,valores,"ID="+id,null);
    if(up!=0){
        Toast.makeText(context,"Se ha añadido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"Fallo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    //Cerramos la BD
        bd.close();
    }
```

Y el error que me da es este:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: inv_numero (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE inventario SET inv_numero=?,inv_tipo=?,inv_nombre=?,inv_imagen=? WHERE ID=1
```

Si intento lanzarle un Select me da un error similar:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: inv_nombre (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT inv_nombre FROM inventario WHERE ID=1
```

Supongo que habrá algún problema o al crear la tabla o al rellenar los datos, pero no doy con la tecla.

He probado a añadir comillas simples a la ID pero tampoco funciona.¿Alguna idea? Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando creas la tabla inventario, no le estas agregando un espacio a los nombres de las columnas.

Por ejemplo:

```
  +INV_NUMERO + "INTEGER NOT NULL,"
```

El resultado seria :

```
"inv_tipoINTEGER NOT NULL"
```

Por lo que falla al crear la tabla. Dale un espacio:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INVENTARIO_NAME + " ("
                +"ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
                +INV_NUMERO + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"  // espacio al princio
                +INV_TIPO + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"  // espacio al princio
                +INV_NOMBRE + " TEXT NOT NULL," // espacio al princio
                +INV_IMAGEN + " INTEGER NOT NULL)"); // espacio al princio
```

Comment: Sabía que sería por una tontería. Lo peor es que ya había solucionado ese error en otra tabla, pero a veces el árbol no te deja ver el bosque. Gracias mil, te doy el válido en cuanto me deje la web :)

Comment: No te preocupes, a mi me pasa cada rato haha.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es precisamente el detallado en el mensaje:

> SQLiteException: no such column: inv_numero (code 1):

Indica que no existe la columna: `inv_numero`

Pero el problema es tu query, agrega espacios para que no quede junto el nombre del campo y el tipo de dato, esta formandose así:

> "inv_numeroINTEGER NOT NULL,".....

debe ser:

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INVENTARIO_NAME + " ("
                +"ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
                +INV_NUMERO + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +INV_TIPO + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +INV_NOMBRE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                +INV_IMAGEN + " INTEGER NOT NULL)");
```

En android, como ya creaste una estructura de la tabla es importante **corregir el query para crear la tabla y posteriormente borrar los datos de la aplicación o eliminarla y volver a agregar una nueva versión** ya que seguramente no se llamara el método `onUpgrade()`  a menos que cambies el `versionCode`.